# writing a catch all mvc route

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am working with MVC4 and looking to write a route but unsure how do so.

On my site I have a number of routes. What I want to achieve is as follows:

- Any url that corresponds to route, the controller action for that route is fired
- But if no controller action is found for a url, I want a particular controller action to be fired eg. www.mywebsite.com/level1/level2/level3 has no corresponding route, so I want to call a particular route and pass to it level1, level2 and level3 in a list of strings as an argument of the controller action. There is no restriction to the number of items.

With this information I will do a check if the data exists in a content management system etc.

Any ideas how I might create a route for the above?

Answer (score 1):

What your suggesting is basically a catch 404. It may not sound elegant because it feels like causing an error and catching it, but a 404 is simply the step taken after not being able to identify a proper route. If the MVC framework had a 'Final Option' route, it would be taken after no proper route was found.

2 approaches

**Route Method**

- // We couldn't find a route to handle the request.  Show the 404 page.
  routes.MapRoute("Error", "{*url}",
      new { controller = "Error", action = "404" }
  );

-

or

### -

**Custom Error Handler in web.config**

```
<customErrors mode="On" >
       <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/CatchallController/CatchallAction" />
</customErrors>
```

The condition raised by no route matching is a 404. This way you direct all non-match to your `~/CatchallController/CatchallAction`

|

Answer (score 0):

You can use an asterisk in your route pattern to signify a "catch-all" ( a "variable-length" route).

e.g. "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{*catchall}"

This will match any url with any number of segments from the catchall segment onwards.

Remember to specify your more specific routes before your more general ones.